# Problem with UEFI locked boot menu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, uefi, bios

I have got into a very big trouble as i cannot change my boot order and also not able to boot from any installations am making on my hard disk.

Recently my harddisk was crashed and i gave it to service center they replaced my HDD am not sure if they changed my default bios password and kept custom but am very sure i have not touched it.Now in the novo button menu if i select boot setup it asks me for PASSWORD which i have never set.

Now i have tried installing several times but it is not picking my ubuntu installation.I have deleted all the drive data which was present for my earlier Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12 version.Currently am able to use only 64 bit LIVE USB v15 ubuntu.

If you would like to have a look at boot repair report i am providing the URL.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13587360/
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13587215/

I would be really grateful if you can help me remove this UEFI locked configuration without opening the box,removing CMOS battery did not helped me.

With Regards

Comment: incase this info of bios version and manufacture helps.

vendor Phoenix tech ltd

Version 5FCM89WW
release 8 27 12
Address oxE0000

Runtime size 128 kb

rom size 6656

Comment: Why not ask the service center for the password?

Comment: hehe they are not that nice people!! i have asked them they are not telling me anything.They said that is out of our scope we won't even touch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually clear a firmware password by setting a jumper or following some other special procedure. You'll need to check the documentation for your computer, though, since the details vary greatly from one machine to another. Removing the battery is usually *not* sufficient to do this.

If that fails, and if it really is a firmware password, then I'd take the computer back to the service center and demand that they fix it, since it sounds like one of their technicians set the password without your permission.

Comment: I have actually taken the chance to open my laptop and remove the cmos battery for some time.Prior to that my laptop was atleast loading the ubuntu OS installed in my system.But after removing the cmos battery it stopped with that also.

Bro,even i suspect the same that they have set it but they are not ready either to fix it or remove it.I am totally  lost what should be done.I have tried few options and ready to follow more if anyone have any suggestion.

Comment: As I said, removing the battery is usually not sufficient on modern computers, which store data in NVRAM, which needs no power to sustain its contents. Thus, you must learn the procedure to clear the NVRAM contents. This is often done by means of a jumper, but details vary so much from one computer to another that you ***MUST*** contact the manufacturer, or at least correspond with somebody who understands the details of your specific computer, to get anywhere.